# how i had to specify .htpasswd file path in .htaccess relative or absolute

Tags: php, .htaccess

I created a password protected folder using .htpasswd. In .htacces how should i specify this .htpasswd file.

like this

```
AuthUserFile http://alertalert.freetzi.com/admin/.htpasswd
```

or

like this

```
AuthUserFile /admin/.htpasswd
```

or any other method. Plz help

Comment: My Site is hosted at http://alertme.freetzi.com/admin is my restricted folder. then how?

Answer (score 2):

You should reference the file using its filesystem path, not anything relative to the web server. So if your site is hosted in the folder `/var/www/localhost/htdocs/`, then you would write:

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/localhost/htdocs/admin/.htpasswd
```